# How do I solve the following system of 2D pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab, python

I dont have a background in maths and this is my first time dealing with pdes, trying to solve
$$
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial n_c}{dt}  \\
\frac{\partial n_p}{dt}  \\
\end{matrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
D_c \nabla^2-k_c-k & 0 \\
k & D_c \nabla^2-k_p   \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
n_c(r,t) \\
n_p(r,t)  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

After some attempt I could see that $n_c$ has an analytical solution, but I dont think $n_p$ has one. What are the tools that I could use to tackle this problem? I'm proficient with Python but could also try learning other language for solving.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $k, k_c, k_p, D_c$ are constants, you can write down an analytical solution for $n_p$ reasonably easily. As you have observed, the PDE for $n_c$ is decoupled from the PDE for $n_p$, and boils down to the equation
$$
\frac{\partial n_c}{\partial t} = (D_c\nabla^2 - k_c - k)n_c
$$
which is effectively a heat equation and can be solved analytically with a variety of techniques (such as separation of variables/Fourier analysis) given appropriate initial/boundary conditions.

Once you have solved for $n_c$, you can now solve for $n_p$, because the equation for $n_p$ is of the form
$$
\frac{\partial n_p}{\partial t} = kf(r,t) + (D_c\nabla^2 - k_p)n_p
$$
where $f(r,t) = n_c(r,t)$. This is an inhomogeneous linear PDE, and assuming you have reasonable initial conditions, it can be solved using [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle). Note that you can use the explicit analytical solution for $n_c$ in the PDE for $n_p$, so there is no issue arising from the equations being coupled: you solve for $n_c$ first, then plug it back into the PDE for $n_p$ and solve from there.